# How to update multiple queries in a single query

Tags: php, mysql

I want to count the no. Of yes in Table 1 :chk1
[image]

And store it in a different table
Table 2: chk2
[image]

The php code i am trying is

```
<?php 
     $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "vsmsdb1");  
    
     $query1 ="UPDATE chk2 t1 SET t1.qty = (select count(*) from chk1 t2 where t2.qw = 'yes' && t1.name = 'qw')";
     $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query1) or die(mysqli_error($connect));  
?>
    
<?php 
     $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "vsmsdb1");  
     $query2 ="UPDATE chk2 t1 SET t1.qty = (select count(*) from chk1 t2 where t2.as = 'yes' && t1.name = 'as')";
     $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query2) or die(mysqli_error($conn));  
?>
```

Bt running this php code is only updating one of the query that is only a single column is getting affected
How do i update all the columns of table2: chk2 counting the no. Of 'yes' from table1: chk1

Of you may assist pl
It can be a single update query or multiple query so that table2: chk2 gets updated in a single php file.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE chk2 t1
SET t1.qty = (select count(*) from chk1 t2 where t2.qw = 'yes' && t1.name = 'qw' OR  t2.zx = 'yes' && t1.name = 'zx' OR t2.we = 'yes' && t1.name = 'we')
```

Using an **OR** in between queries  will do the job